# getting distance between two location using geocoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api, google-geocoding-api

I want to find the distance between two location using google API. I want output to be look like - "The distance between location 1 and location 2 is 500 miles ( distance here is example purposes )", but how can i get the desired output as the current program is showing various output ( which i cant use to get he desired output ) . can you guys please show me the way or show me what is the exact procedure to do it?

```
   import urllib
   import json
   serviceurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

   while True:
   address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
   if len(address) < 1 : break

   url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': address})
   print 'Retrieving', url
   uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
   data = uh.read()
   print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'

   try: js = json.loads(str(data))
   except: js = None
   if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
    print '==== Failure To Retrieve ===='
    print data
    continue

   print json.dumps(js, indent=4)

   lat = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
   lng = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
   print 'lat',lat,'lng',lng
   location = js['results'][0]['formatted_address']
   print location
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know `lat` and `lon`, use the geopy package:

```
In [1]: from geopy.distance import great_circle

In [2]: newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)

In [3]: cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)

In [4]: great_circle(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).kilometers
Out[4]: 864.4567616296598
```

Answer (score 4):

Google has a specific api for that, it's called  **[Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/)**.

> **Distance & duration for multiple destinations and transport modes**.
>   Retrieve duration and distance values based on the recommended route
>   between start and end points.

---

If you just need the distance between two points on the globe you may want to use the [Haversine formula](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe#Python)